# Tools to show information about my Wi-Fi connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Is there any tool that shows more information about my Wi-Fi connection? Like connection type: 802.11g or 802.11n? 20MHz or 40MHz? signal strength? dB? etc...

Comment: http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/

Comment: That's for all SSIDs around me. I was looking for tool to show information about my current connection as Windows' Network and Sharing Center doesn't provide too much info.

Comment: inSSIder gives you all those info, for all available network.

Comment: @Stan If it's for all SSIDs, it should also show your current connection.